# Temporarily block signals between two QObjects

Tags: qt, signals, qobject, slot

I would like to generically and temporarily block the signals between two `QObjects` without modifying the other signals/slots behavior, and without knowing their contexts.

Something like [QObject::blockSignals(bool)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#blockSignals), but only acting between two `QObjects`.

That is, implementing the following `SignalBlocker::blockSignals(bool)` function:

```
class SignalBlocker {

public:
  SignalBlocker(QObject *sender, QObject *receiver) :
    mSender(sender), mReceiver(receiver) {}
  void blockSignals(bool block);

private:
  QObject *mSender, *mReceiver;
}
```

It would be possible by disconneting and re-connecting the objects, but first the list of signals/slots would have to be stored.
Introspection methods don't seem to be powerful enough to achieve this (I looked at `QMetaObject` and `QSignalSpy` without success).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

QT have no capabilities to disable signal-slot pair only. Try this workaround:

```
struct SignalDisabler
{
    SignalDisabler(const QObject *sender, const char *signal, const QObject *receiver, const char *member)
        : sender(sender)
        , signal(signal)
        , receiver(receiver)
        , member(member)
    {
        QObject::disconnect(sender, signal, receiver, member);
    }

    ~SignalDisabler()
    {
        QObject::connect(sender, signal, receiver, member);
    }

    const QObject *sender;
    const char *signal;
    const QObject *receiver;
    const char *member;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

since you want that the sender and the reciever will not send signals within that scope, i would just try to use `blockSignals(bool)`

```
class SignalBlocker{
public:
SignalBlocker(QObject* obj)
{
   _o = obj;
   _o->blockSignals(true);
}
~SignalBlocker()
{
   _o->blockSignals(false);
}
private:
   QObject* _o;
};
```

and now just use

```
SignalBlocker sb1(sender);
SignalBlocker sb2(reciever);
//...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't solve my problem, because sender and receiver are in this case completely blocked (they cannot send messages to a third QObject, while this is what I need).

Comment: maybe its possible to create a class like `SignalBlocker` and give the objects a template function pointer of what you want to block ... so it would be blocking just the signal you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disconnect(sender, 0, receiver, 0);` to disconnect all `sender`'s signals from all `receiver`'s slots.

Comment: Indeed, but I would like to be able to retrieve the same state as before the disconnection when reconnecting the Object. So before the disconnection, I should list all the signals/slots connections between the sender and the receiver (and this is the point I'm unable to do).

Comment: Try to use something like `void QObject::connectNotify ( const char * signal ) [virtual protected]` or `void QObject::disconnectNotify ( const char * signal ) [virtual protected]` to get a list of connected/disconnected signals, but I don't think you're doing right things. Why do you need that?