# QListWidget: change selection without triggering selectionChanged

Tags: qt, qt5, pyqt5, qlistwidget, selectionchanged

I'm using a QListWidget to control and display some state.

Now to control the state, user-selection in the widget is used.
to respond to that, I've connected the selectionChanged signal.

However the state can change by itsself and when that happens, I have a complete new state and want the selection to change.

To achieve that I'm iterating over the state and the items like this:

```
    for item, s in zip(items, state):
        item.setSelected(s)
```

However this triggers selectionChanged (even in every single iteration)
I don't want that to happen at all.

is there another way to respond to the selection-change?

Comment: You could block the signals, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633086/qt-block-temporarily-signals-between-2-qobjects) in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the [`QSignalBlocker`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html) class. Before calling a function which emits a signal, instantiate a `QSignalBlocker` object.

```
// ui->ListWidget is available.
{
    QSignalBlocker blocker( ui->ListWidget );
    for ( auto item : items )
    {
        item->setSelected();
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, sounds promising
1. for how long is the signal blocked then? don't i have to release the blockage somehow?
2. python code? (i didnt mention it explicitly, but the tag i used an my code: im using pyqt5)

Comment: In C++ the blocker will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. Or you can use `ui->ListWidget->blockSignals( true );` and when you want signals again ui->ListWidget->blockSignals( false );